# Can users add records to the front-end of a split database in MS Access 2013?

Tags: database, ms-access, frontend, backend, ms-access-2013

My company is looking to split our staff database to ensure constant access and readability for all departments who require it. We performed some research and found out splitting the database and potentially making it an executable (for the front-end) would be the best idea.

However, the snag in the line that we reached is that we have certain forms in our Access database that require users to add in new records (vendor receipts, training records, etc.). Is it possible for the front-end user to add a new record using their part of the split database, or is that only something internal staff can do?

Also, if this is possible, would any extra action be required on the internal systems staff's part to replicate/update the data to our back end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backend is what is accessed by all users via the frontend(s).

Thus, reading and writing data will go to the backend for any user. That's the idea of having a shared backend.